# Dynamic cast unexpectedly returns null for a type, but only sometimes and not for other types

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have this dynamic cast, which I would expect to always work:

```
BaseClass *b = new DerivedClass();
DerivedClass *d = dynamic_cast<DerivedClass *>(b);
```

Well, of course I'm posting this question because it doesn't always work. Here's the situation:

- `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass` are both defined in the same framework.
- This framework is used in two different applications.
- For the first application, the dynamic cast works fine (returns `b`).
- For the second application, the dynamic cast doesn't work (returns null).
- For the second application, RTTI seems to be enabled because dynamic casts for other types work.

So what could be causing the dynamic cast for this one type to fail in one application?

Comment: Without more information, we can't answer this question. There are many reasons this could fail.

Comment: "So what could be causing the dynamic cast for this one type to fail in one application?". Because 'b' is not actually the type you think it is? The code above is probably not the same as in your application, and so is misleading. As mentioned there is not enough information to work out why.

Comment: @codah: Actually I did try that exact code (with my type names substituted in, of course). So it's not misleading.

Comment: @templatetypedef: What information would you like? I ruled out every possible cause I knew of from reading related SO questions (wrong type, lack of RTTI). Since the code is huge, I distilled it down to as much as I knew was relevant. Can you suggest any other information that would be relevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thing that can happen with GCC is if some of your code is static-linked and some is dynamic-linked. Or if the same class is defined in two different dynamic libraries.

For example, a type SomeClass in the static linked code will produce a SomeClass typeinfo. And the SomeClass in the dynamic linked code will also produce a SomeClass typeinfo.

What I have seen is that *most* of the code will point to the dynamic SomeClass typeinfo while all of the code in the static-linked block will point to its internal copy of SomeClass typeinfo.

Since GCC determines types for RTTI and exception handling via typeinfo pointers, this means that as far as it is concerned SomeClass and SomeClass are not the same type.

Now, Microsoft with Windows, probably because they deal with a lot more static linked code and old binary libraries that can't be recompiled, decided to do strcmp name comparisons of types which means that their RTTI and exception handling is a lot slower but works in almost all cases.

Comment: That was it! The second application was linking to both the framework defining `BaseClass` and `DynamicClass` and a static library defining these classes. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had this happen to me once. 
The problem boiled down to the visibility of C++ symbols in the framework. 
Specifically, the symbols were hidden for some reason.

Now, `dynamic_cast` requires, in the derived class, to point to some type information for the base class, which can't happen if the symbol is not visible.

Bottom line, setting the visibility for the affected classes like that :

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) SomeClass
{
    /* ... */
};
```

solved the issue for us

Comment: Interesting. That turned out not to solve the problem in this case (I also checked for related issues with symbol visibility using the `nm` and `c++filt` commands), but maybe it can help someone else.