# GTest/GMock WhenDynamicCastTo fails to match argument

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

### Background

I have large C++ project where visitor pattern is used. All libraries in project are static. To test if proper events are triggered I wrote some gtest.

### Problem

When I wrote some unit test it fails when everything indicates it should pass. The gtest log says:

```
unknown file: error: 
Unexpected mock function call - taking default action specified at:
F:\repos\someProject\UnitTests\PacketsParserTest.cpp(47):
    Function call: process(00000022E00FE110)
          Returns: true
Google Mock tried the following 1 expectation, but it didn't match:
F:\repos\someProject\UnitTests\PacketsParserTest.cpp(58): EXPECT_CALL(*this, process(WhenDynamicCastTo<Event*>(Pointee(innerMatcher))))...
  Expected arg #0: when dynamic_cast to class RegistryEvent * __ptr64, points to a value that is anything
           Actual: 00000022E00FE110, NULL (of type class RegistryEvent * __ptr64)
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
unknown file: error: 
Unexpected mock function call - taking default action specified at:
F:\repos\someProject\UnitTests\PacketsParserTest.cpp(47):
    Function call: process(00000022E00FE388)
          Returns: true
Google Mock tried the following 1 expectation, but it didn't match:
F:\repos\someProject\UnitTests\PacketsParserTest.cpp(58): EXPECT_CALL(*this, process(WhenDynamicCastTo<Event*>(Pointee(innerMatcher))))...
  Expected arg #0: when dynamic_cast to class RegistryEvent * __ptr64, points to a value that is anything
           Actual: 00000022E00FE388, NULL (of type class RegistryEvent * __ptr64)
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

As you can see form this log expected argument should have type: `class RegistryEvent *` with any content. It complains that could not match argument, but it says it received argument is of same type: `class RegistryEvent *`!

I've tried to provide Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, but this test just passes correctly:

```cpp
#include <gmock/gmock.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <memory>

class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const = 0;
};

class AEvent : public Base {
public:
    ~AEvent() override = default;

    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<AEvent>(*this);
    }
};

class BEvent : public Base {
public:
    ~BEvent() override = default;

    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<BEvent>(*this);
    }
};

class CEvent : public Base {
public:
    ~CEvent() override = default;

    std::unique_ptr<Base> clone() const override
    {
        return std::make_unique<CEvent>(*this);
    }
};

class Consumer {
public:
    virtual ~Consumer() = default;

    virtual bool process(Base* event) = 0;
};

bool foo(int someInput, Consumer* consumer)
{
    switch (someInput) {
    case 0: {
        AEvent a;
        return consumer->process(&a);
    }
    case 1: {
        BEvent b;
        return consumer->process(&b);
    }
    case 2: {
        CEvent c;
        return consumer->process(&c);
    }
    }
    return false;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
using testing::Return;
using testing::WhenDynamicCastTo;

class MockConsumer : public Consumer {
public:
    ~MockConsumer() override = default;

    MockConsumer()
    {
        ON_CALL(*this, process(testing::_)).WillByDefault(Return(true));
    }

    template <typename Event>
    void expectEvent(const testing::Matcher<Event>& innerMatcher = testing::_)
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(*this, process(WhenDynamicCastTo<Event*>(Pointee(innerMatcher))));
    }

    MOCK_METHOD(bool, process, (Base * event), (override));
};

class MagicTest : public testing::Test { 
public:
    bool doFoo(int someData)
    {
        return foo(someData, &m_consumer);
    }

    testing::NiceMock<MockConsumer> m_consumer;
};

TEST_F(MagicTest, FooZeroTriggersAEvent)
{
    m_consumer.expectEvent<AEvent>();
    ASSERT_TRUE(doFoo(0));
}

TEST_F(MagicTest, FooOneTriggersBEvent)
{
    m_consumer.expectEvent<BEvent>();
    ASSERT_TRUE(doFoo(1));
}

TEST_F(MagicTest, FooThreeTriggersCEvent)
{
    m_consumer.expectEvent<CEvent>();
    ASSERT_TRUE(doFoo(2));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hfzdW4js7

It replicates very accurately my actual test, but doesn't replicate issue.

In my test suite I have other test cases with same pattern for different events which are working correctly. I do not see any reason why this matcher works for one event and fails for the other `RegistryEvent`.

### Analysis

My first thought was that RTTI is broken, but I ensured that all virtual methods are defined in cpp file of translation unit, so not duplicates of v-table is created.

Also my project uses only static libraries so even if some v-table is duplicated linker should be able to merge it.

Note this matcher I used is shorthand version of visitor pattern. I have lots of different kinds of events so defining mock for Visitor which has virtual method for each event type is a bit annoying (not I need return `true` as default behavior), so I wish to avoid that.

### Question

Does anyone have a clue why `WhenDynamicCastTo` can fail match this event even if log says proper event was received?
Is this some configuration issue, build inconsistency?
Anything what could help me do some extra test to find root cause.

Comment: Any multiple inheritance involved? Any non-polymorphics base classes involved (i.e. missing `virtual` in a base class)? Have you tried debugging and stepping into the `WhenDynamicCastTo` code to see what the debugger is telling your about the types passed to `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: no multiple inheritance, no virtual inheritance. All events are direct descendants of `Base` as in example. It should works (and it works in case of one event and fails in case of other).

Comment: Strange. For shared libraries, I know that this can happen (see eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150436/3740047) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652408/3740047)). As suggested, I'd try to debug into the Google test code and see what the debugger tells you about the types. You could also add logging and log e.g. the address of the objects, of the return type of `typeid` and the names returned by `typeid`.